# Como mover e rotacionar onde for o Click do mouse?

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d, rotação, física

Criei um *script* em que meu personagem se movimenta pelo *click* do *mouse* mas tem um problema: ele não esta girando na posição **Y**, essa é a condição tive que criar para que ele rotacione no eixo **X**:

```
else if (target.x >= target.z)
```

Mas gostaria que quando ele fosse para cima ele rotacionava e ficasse com a cabeça virada para cima.

Criei esse script para q ele girasse para cima e para baixo, mas quando eu clico para ele ir pra esquerda script acaba ficando assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
var angle = Mathf.Atan2(target.y - transform.position.y, target.x - transform.position.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, angle);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
public float speed = 5.0f;

private Vector3 target;
private Vector3 target_rot;

private Animator dash;
private Animator jumpe;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    target = transform.position;
    dash = GetComponent<Animator> ();
    jumpe = GetComponent<Animator> ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)){  
        target = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        target.z = transform.position.x;
        dash.SetInteger ("condicao", 1);
        target_rot = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    } else if (transform.position == target) 
    {    
        dash.SetInteger ("condicao", 2); 
    }

    if (target.x <= target.z) {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3 (-1, 1, 1); 
    } else if (target.x >= target.z) {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1, 1, 1); 
    } 

    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, target,   speed *Time.deltaTime);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Você está usando alterações de escala (tamanho) do objeto com valor negativo no eixo X para simular a rotação na direção esquerda-direita. Isto é, ao fazer `transform.localScale = new Vector3 (-1, 1, 1);`, você simplesmente "flipa" (espelha em 180 graus) a imagem naquele eixo. Não é a melhor solução do mundo, mas funciona. O problema é que depois você quer rotacionar o objeto da forma "correta" (isto é, utilizando rotação angular para fazê-lo apontar na direção do alvo). Só que a sua "flipagem" no eixo X continua, de forma que o objeto girando e flipando acaba ficando de cabeça pra baixo.

A solução é você não flipar o objeto no eixo X, e somente utilizar a rotação angular. Pra evitar que ele fique de cabeça pra baixo, você flipa **no eixo Y** apenas quando a rotação fizer ele ficar invertido. Isto ocorre quando o objeto se move pra cima e pra esquerda, ou pra baixo e pra esquerda. Ou seja, somente quando o ângulo for maior do que 90º (quando ele se move pra cima e pra esquerda) ou for menor do que 90º (quando ele se move pra baixo e pra esquerda).

> Isso se dá porque a rotação na Unity é contabilizada de 0º a 360º a partir da direção de "frente" do objeto, com valor positivo quando girando em sentido anti-horário e com valor negativo quando girando em sentido horário.

O código abaixo, então, ilustra uma possível solução. Removi a parte de animação, porque não existe no meu exemplo. E adicionei um raio de desaceleração, pra que o sprite se mova mais elegantemente ao se aproximar do alvo (e não fique pulando como um maluco quando em cima do alvo).

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Teste: MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 5.0f;
    public float reductionRadius = 1.0f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Use GetMouseButton para um efeito continuo. Caso contrário, vc precisará ficar
        // clicando para que o personagem se mova (porque GetMouseButtonDown só é True no
        // frame em que o mouse foi pressionado! Já GetMouseButton é True enquanto o mouse
        // estiver pressionado!).
        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            // Use posições do mundo, funciona melhor
            Vector3 target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

            // Como o jogo é 2D, vc não precisa de informação no eixo Z
            target.z = 0f;

            // Rotaciona o personagem em direção ao alvo
            var angle = Mathf.Atan2(target.y - transform.position.y, target.x - transform.position.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle);

            // Garante que ele não fique "de cabeça pra baixo", flipando o sprite no eixo Y
            // se o ângulo de movimento absoluto for maior do que 90 graus (isto é, sem importar
            // se ele está indo pra cima ou pra baixo)
            if(Mathf.Abs(angle) > 90f)
                transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, -1f, 1f);
            else
                transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f);

            // Move o personagem em direção ao alvo (reduzindo a velocidade conforme
            // ele se aproxima do alvo, a partir de um raio de redução configurado)
            float dist = (target - transform.position).magnitude;
            float movement = speed * Time.deltaTime;
            if(dist < reductionRadius)
                movement *= dist / reductionRadius;

            transform.position += (target - transform.position).normalized * movement;
        }
    }
}
```

Ilustração do código funcionando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observe que o personagem "pisca" quando o sprite é invertido (isto é, ele muda imediatamente de lado quando a "flipagem" acontece). Foi por isso que eu disse: essa abordagem funciona, mas não fica realmente boa. Pra fazer algo mais profissional, use uma animação de transição entre esquerda e direita.